# Making an automated chessboard

Tags: electromagnetism, camera, hall-effect, magnet, reed-switch

I want to create an automated chessboard. At the moment, I'm making the project and deciding what technology to use to detect which piece is at what position and how to move them. I'm not so skilled in electronics so I'm reading online and trying to find an efficient and cost-friendly solution.

I read about reed switches, but these only detect if a piece is in a position, without telling which piece is it. The same goes for hall effect sensors. Then I thought about using computer vision, but placing a camera on top of everything would be bulky.

So a nice idea could be using rfid tags under every piece. Also magnets have to be placed to move the pieces and small leds to show the possible moves in the board. Magnetic field could be a problem.

I wanted to ask, if this idea could work from an electronic aspect, and if there are other technologies to be used.

Comment: Yes it could work but, whether it's a good idea or cost-effective is something else.

Comment: Would you be willing to collaborate on this?? It sounds like a fun project, I'm interested in working together.

Comment: Chess pieces have defined start positions. So whatever piece you pick up and place down, you should already know what piece it was and what possible moves it has.

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions on EE.SE, [if you search for `chess`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=chess).

Comment: You can just [buy one](https://squareoffnow.com/).

Comment: you already asked this at https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/making-an-automated-chessboard ... please do not crosspost

Comment: Yeah, you're completely out of your depth skill-wise.  It's perfectly fine to use the thought of such inventions *as an inspiration* to go skill up your technical chops.  However, dream ideas where you have no idea where to even start, doesn't belong on StackExchange. Also (https://stackoverflow.com/q/75697689/9473773) too. Did you try 4chan/diy?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I lightly edited your comment, preserving the key messages. For a new contributor that was "a bit stiff" for an introduction. It's sometimes hard to be sure how comments will come across. For a new controbutor the "be nice" policy suggests we lean towards the mild side.